# How to compile STM Blackpill code in Keil uVision 5?

Tags: compilation, keil, stm32f4

I want to work with BlackPill STM32**F411CE** using Keil uVision 5. Unfortunately, Keil is not able to compile program simply because it doesn't recognize STM32F4 family for some reason. Here are the steps I took:
First I downloaded necessary packs needed using **Pack Installer**:
[image]

After installation, F4 family is not present inside **Options for Target > Device**:
[image]

Therefore, Keil is not able to compile code, and gives this **error**:
[image]

Here are some info about current version of Keil I use:
[image]